# How to check if an activity is running in background/foreground from a service?

Tags: android, android-activity, service

I have created a service which starts from an activity's onCreate and stops on the activity's onDestroy method. Now I have to check from a method of the service that whether the activity is running in foreground/background(for some cases like application is forcefully closed). How can I do that?

1. I need to do this coz as far I know there is no guarantee of calling onDestroy method of an activity if any the application is forcefully closed or any kind of crash. So, my service which starts when my activity launches won't stop after any crash or any forceful closing event.
2. I have seen [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172092/check-if-activity-is-running-from-service) where foreground activities can be checked. But I need to check a running activity in whatever state (either foreground or background)

Answer (score 12):

**Final Update**

To check for all activities:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
super.onStop();

    if (AppConstants.isAppSentToBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
        // Do what ever you want after app close simply Close session

    }
}
```

Method to check our app is running or not:

```
public static boolean isAppSentToBackground(final Context context) {

    try {
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        // The first in the list of RunningTasks is always the foreground
        // task.
        RunningTaskInfo foregroundTaskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0);
        String foregroundTaskPackageName = foregroundTaskInfo.topActivity
                .getPackageName();// get the top fore ground activity
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        PackageInfo foregroundAppPackageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(
                foregroundTaskPackageName, 0);

        String foregroundTaskAppName = foregroundAppPackageInfo.applicationInfo
                .loadLabel(pm).toString();

        // Log.e("", foregroundTaskAppName +"----------"+
        // foregroundTaskPackageName);
        if (!foregroundTaskAppName.equals("Your App name")) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("isAppSentToBackground", "" + e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Answer updated again**

Use the below method with your package name.It will return true if any of your activity is in foreground.

```
public boolean isForeground(String myPackage){
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
 List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > runningTaskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1); 

     ComponentName componentInfo = runningTaskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
   if(componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(myPackage)) return true;
return false;
}
```

**Answer Updated**

Check this link first [Checking if an Android application is running in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667022/android-is-application-running-in-background)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#lcycles is a description of the Life Cycle of an android application.

The method onPause() gets called when the activity goes into the background. So you can deactivate the update notifications in this method.

```
public static boolean isApplicationSentToBackground(final Context context) {
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
    if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
      ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
      if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
```

add permisions in the menifest as well

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I dont want to use any method of activity, coz I want to check from a service that whether a specific activity/application is running or not...

Comment: Thanks, your last edit fulfill my task partially, now how can I check from a running service whether all the activities of my application is in background or not....

Comment: @Override
protected void onStop() {
super.onStop();

    if (AppConstants.isAppSentToBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
        // Do what ever you want after app close simply Close session

    }
}

Comment: To get isApplicationInBackground value, you have made a list of running foreground applications, and check whether my application is over there or not. But there are two cases for an application, not to be in the foreground list: 1. if my application is really in background or 2. my application is crashed and not in background mode. So by those try catch block codes, how can I be sure that my application is not crashed???

Comment: when your application is crashed, it is not in the background list. it  is destroyed. being on background means that onPause has been called on the application

Comment: yes, I have said it also.(Probably I cant make you understand my comments) My very simple requirement is to make a background application list (not only foreground app list).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47742/discussion-between-hassaan-rabbani-and-crazylearner)

Comment: if there are three or four apps in background . it will get the latest one because you have set tasks.get(0) and getting  am.getRunningTasks(1). what will happen then

Comment: This method (isApplicationSentToBackground) checks if CURRENT ACTIVITY sent to background, NOT APPLICATION.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, [`getRunningTasks()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks%28int%29) has been deprecated since Android API 21 (Android Lollipop):

> This method was deprecated in API level 21. As of LOLLIPOP, this
>   method is no longer available to third party applications: the
>   introduction of document-centric recents means it can leak person
>   information to the caller. For backwards compatibility, it will still
>   return a small subset of its data: at least the caller's own tasks,
>   and possibly some other tasks such as home that are known to not be
>   sensitive.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but the question is about checking an activity from a service within the same application, so wouldn't "at least the caller's own tasks" cover that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this method to check your app is in background or not:

```
public boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
        boolean isInBackground = true;
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
            for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
                if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                    for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                        if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                            isInBackground = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
            ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
            if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                isInBackground = false;
            }
        }

        return isInBackground;
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18038399/how-to-check-if-activity-is-in-foreground-or-in-visible-background) link & especially check the Answer Which shows this part of code

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

 public static boolean isActivityVisible() {
return activityVisible;
}  

public static void activityResumed() {
 activityVisible = true;
}

public static void activityPaused() {
activityVisible = false;
 }

private static boolean activityVisible;
}
```

Hope this help you.