# ActivityManager.getRunningTasks is deprecated android

Tags: android, push-notification, deprecated, activity-manager

I am working on push notification in android where i am using a below method to show notification, but the problem is that now ActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1);  is being deprecated. From one stackoverflow question i read that: " you can use `getAppTasks()` returning a `List<AppTask>` where you can get the `RecentTaskInfo` with `getTaskInfo`" but i can't figure it out how to use it. Please help me out here in this regard.

```
private void postNotification(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
        try {
            if (intent == null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Receiver intent null");
            } else {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (action.equals("com.ziza.cy.UPDATE_STATUS")) {

                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras()
                            .getString("com.parse.Data"));

                    String type = json.getString("type");

                    if (type.equals("AlertNotification")) {

                        String msg = json.getString("header");
                        String title = "ncy";

                        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) ctx
                                .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                        List<RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
                        ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;

                        // don't show notification if app is in foreground
                        if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equalsIgnoreCase(
                                ctx.getPackageName())) {

                            // send broadcast receiver
                            Intent intentBroad = new Intent();
                            intentBroad.setAction(Constants.sNOTIFICATION);
                            intentBroad.putExtra("msg", msg);
                            intentBroad.putExtra("title", title
                                    + " "
                                    + taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClass()
                                            .getSimpleName());
                            ctx.sendBroadcast(intentBroad);
                        } else {
                            // Activity Not Running
                            // Generate Notification

                            Intent intnt = new Intent(ctx, LogInActivity.class);
                            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent
                                    .getActivity(ctx, 0, intnt, 0);
                            intnt.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                                    ctx)
                                    .setContentTitle(title)
                                    .setContentText(msg)
                                    .setTicker(msg)
                                    .setSound(
                                            RingtoneManager
                                                    .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                                    .setStyle(
                                            new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                                    .bigText(msg))
                                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.iconed)
                                    .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

                            Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager
                                    .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                            builder.setSound(alarmSound);
                            builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
                            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx
                                    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                            notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This should help you get started

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.AppTask> tasks = activityManager.getAppTasks();

for (ActivityManager.AppTask task : tasks) {
    Log.d(TAG, "stackId: " + task.getTaskInfo().stackId);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer here. Can you please explain me according to my following condition, i want to embed it like the following condition: ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
      
      List<RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
      ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;

Comment: this only returns my activity task

Answer (score 46):

**This should work for the pre Lollipop devices as well as for Lollipop devices**

```
public static boolean isBackgroundRunning(Context context) {
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
            if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                    if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                        //If your app is the process in foreground, then it's not in running in background
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        return true;
    }
```

Edit: It should return true if the app is in background, not the opposite

Comment: is there any permission need to add in Manifest? like `android.permission.GET_TASKS` or `android.permission.REAL_GET_TASKS`

Comment: Thank you it's working without adding any permissions

Answer (score 5):

May you want this:

```
/***
 * Checking Whether any Activity of Application is running or not
 * @param context
 * @return
 */
public static boolean isForeground(Context context) {

    // Get the Activity Manager
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    // Get a list of running tasks, we are only interested in the last one,
    // the top most so we give a 1 as parameter so we only get the topmost.
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> task = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();

    // Get the info we need for comparison.
    ComponentName componentInfo = task.get(0).importanceReasonComponent;

    // Check if it matches our package name.
    if(componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName()))
        return true;

    // If not then our app is not on the foreground.
    return false;
}
```

Comment: getRunningAppProcesses(); returns just one app which is running iteself it does not show all background apps. i'm using android lollipop and above

Answer (score 3):

```
   val cn: ComponentName
    val am = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
    cn = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        am.appTasks[0].taskInfo.topActivity
    } else {
        am.getRunningTasks(1)[0].topActivity
    }
```

This is work for me

Comment: getRunningTasks is no longer supported or it is deprecated. So, your code is not able to run.

Answer (score 2):

in Kotlin

```
fun isAppRunning(context: Context): Boolean {
  val activityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
  return activityManager.appTasks
    .filter { it.taskInfo != null }
    .filter { it.taskInfo.baseActivity != null }
    .any { it.taskInfo.baseActivity.packageName == context.packageName }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
assert activityManager != null;
List<ActivityManager.AppTask> tasks = activityManager.getAppTasks();
String topClassName = tasks.get(0).getTaskInfo().topActivity.getClassName();
```