# How can we get number of activities in activity stack android.

Tags: android

How can we get number of activities in activity stack android. As getrunningTask() has been deprecated,please help out.

Comment: does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31156313/activitymanager-getrunningtasks-is-deprecated-android) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you have to use now the :

```
    List<ActivityManager.AppTask>   getAppTasks()
```

Comment: If you are not sure, then this should be in comments, right?

Comment: this won't support the older version of android.

Comment: you can use if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)