# ActivityManager get topActivity package name

Tags: android, android-activity, background-process, activity-manager

I have a same question. I'm use this code, to get a packageName on application running in topActivity from my devise

```
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, activityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName());
```

When my app is run, I see my app package name in log, it's ok. If I try curtail my activity, I see in log my home screen app package name, it's true too, but if i launch next app, for example whats app or else, in log i see my app package name again! Why, I don't understand. My app have permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"></uses-permission>
```

Help my please!

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31156313/activitymanager-getrunningtasks-is-deprecated-android

Comment: Thank you, but this question not for my. I do not need check background my app or no. I need get package name application that the user is using at the present time.