# How to check if my app is still running in an Android service?

Tags: android, delphi, android-service, delphi-10.1-berlin, android-service-binding

I'm starting to develop an Android sticky service for my app with Delphi 10.1 Berlin, but I haven't found any tutorial or book that get into it, so I'm asking:

Which is the simplest way to detect if my app is still running or has been killed by the OS/user?

Comment: take a look to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12172218/3023833

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if Activity is running from Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172092/check-if-activity-is-running-from-service)

Comment: Pawel Glowacki's book Expert Delphi has a lot of topics and Android Services in one of those!

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look for the process id by package name and see if it is still active.

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> pids = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
int processid = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < pids.size(); i++) {
    ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo info = pids.get(i);
    if (info.processName.equalsIgnoreCase("packageNameSearchingFor")) {
       processid = info.pid; //found it, we are running
    } 
}
```

Or you can simply store a shared value in public shared pref or database accessible through ContentProvider that is updated when in foreground or background to check. Either way is fine.