# Open activity from Foreground service

Tags: java, android, service

I have an app that needs to run 24/7.
I know that android OS kills the process of my app after some time in the background, so i have a Foreground service which is sticky.
Now the thing is, that i want the service to check if my app is running, and if it is not, then i want the service to start the app. Is it possible?

Comment: Not the same thing at all..

Answer (score 1):

After onStop your activity will  be invisible. If you want to see that your activity running, i.e., on the [foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172092/check-if-activity-is-running-from-service);

```
public boolean isForeground(String myPackage) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> runningTaskInfo = manager.getRunningTasks(1); 
    ComponentName componentInfo = runningTaskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
    return componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(myPackage);
}
```

If it is not in the foreground, you can use below otherwise;

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyMainActivity.class);
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startActivity(i);
```

- Note; another method, you can send message to your service from your activity about its status
- or, use idolon's idea][2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667022/checking-if-an-android-application-is-running-in-the-background);

Comment: Yea, but how can the Foreground service check if the app is running or not?

Comment: But if it is running, it wont just "bring it back", it will call it's onCreate() and will create a new instance of it.

Comment: So that's exactly what im asking...how can i know if the app is running or not ?

Comment: if it is in the foreground it is running! use the isForeground boolean function.

Comment: Eventually what i did was using this code:
`Intent i = new Intent(this, MyMainActivity.class);
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startActivity(i);`
In the foreground service onCreate().

Now if android will kill my process, the service will restart and it will bring up the application.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of app is it? I think such types of apps can be very annoying for users. 
I am not sure what exactly functionality your app have, but are you sure that you can't achieve that same functionality with using [AlarmManger](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) or [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler) ?

Comment: What do you mean by very annoying for users? is whats'app also very annoying because it is running 24/7? The app is for private use only and this is the request..

Comment: @Ohados , if it's some special case, maybe it's fine, I am just saying that usual Android user can be mad on such types of apps, that running all the time and users will see that your app wastes a lot of battery and will remove your app, so my point is does your app really need to be alive all the time?

Comment: There are can be a lot of different apps that may require it. For example an app for taxi drivers.